# Validating and accessing multiple on-page forms with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have multiple dynamically-generated forms (for uploading files) on one page that need validation (though the forms are submitted one at a time):
The format is like this (where X in the `id` of the form is a digit):

```
<form class="uploader" method="post" action="?task=edit" 
id="sectionsX" name="sections" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <button class=" btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, if valid, would like to change the `button` HTML as it submit.
The following code does not work:

I also do not need ALL forms to be validated - only the one that was submitted, obviously. Does that happen with the `each` loop below?

```
 $('.uploader').each(function () {
    $(this).validate({
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            alert('Please be sure to fill out all mandatory fields');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // <- pass 'form' argument in
            $(this).find("button").html('Processing...').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            form.submit(); // <- use 'form' argument here.
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: It's not working because the plugin is not triggered by `<button>` unless you use a `type="submit"` attribute.  So trying to use the `submitHandler` to change the button into a submit is never going to happen.   It will not hit the `submitHandler` function unless you use a `type="submit"` `button` or `input` in the first place.

Comment: @Sparky - of course it's a `type=submit` button, this is just the simplified code. Added in for clarity.

Comment: *"I also do not need ALL forms to be validated - only the one that was submitted, obviously. Does that happen with the each loop below?"*  - Of course not.  The `.validate()` method is just the initialization setup for each form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `$(this)` inside of the `submitHandler` callback function, you'll need to assign it to a variable.  Try `var myform = $(this)`

```
$('.uploader').each(function() {
    var myform = $(this);
    myform.validate({
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            alert('Please be sure to fill out all mandatory fields');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // <- pass 'form' argument in
            myform.find("button").html('Processing...').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            //form.submit(); // <- use 'form' argument here.
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/q4sy1vfe/](https://jsfiddle.net/q4sy1vfe/)**

I commented out `form.submit()` so you can actually see that the button is altered and disabled.